# change size rounded button in java

Tags: java, size, jbutton, shapes

Hi I am programming a game and i thought a rounded button would look nice but i am curious how do i change the size of said button to something bigger? here is my code

```html
public JavaApplication3(String label) {
    super(label);
    Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
    size.width = size.height = Math.max(size.width,size.height);
    setPreferredSize(size);

    setContentAreaFilled(false);
  }

  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (getModel().isArmed()) {
      g.setColor(Color.RED);
    } else {
      g.setColor(Color.yellow);
    }
    g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1,getSize().height-1);

    super.paintComponent(g);
  }

  protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(getForeground());
    g.drawOval(0, 0, getSize().width-1,     getSize().height-1);
  }

  Shape shape;
  public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    if (shape == null || 
      !shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
      shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    return shape.contains(x, y);
  }
```

Hope someone can help :)

Comment: I don't quite understand what your code is doing here, perhaps you could explain it some more please?

Answer (score 0):

this changes the size of your button with every time you click on it.

```
addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("klick");
            setSize(new Dimension(newSizeWidth, newSizeHeight));
        }
    });
}
```

just call the

```
 setSize(new Dimension(newSizeWidth, newSizeHeight));
```

method.

here is some working code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class test2 extends JButton {

    int width = 100;
    int height = 100;

    public test2(String label) {
        super(label);

        setSize(width, height);

        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("klick");
                setSize(new Dimension(width--, height--));
            }
        });
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (getModel().isArmed()) {
            System.out.println(width + " " + height);

            g.setColor(Color.RED);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.yellow);
        }
        g.fillOval(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);

        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(getForeground());
        g.drawOval(0, 0, getSize().width - 1, getSize().height - 1);
    }

    Shape shape;

    public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
        if (shape == null || !shape.getBounds().equals(getBounds())) {
            shape = new Ellipse2D.Float(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }
        return shape.contains(x, y);
    }

    static JFrame f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setSize(200, 200);
        f.add(new test2("label"));
        f.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I meant just like change how big the button is like constant not getting smaller from my code

Comment: well, i wanted you to understand what you are doing. Not just copy/pasting. ;-) you can change the size (like it is mentioned in the answer) with the method setSize();